# Switching between 2 images html & javscript

Tags: javascript, html

I write this code, when I click on that specifiek place on the image it is going to the next image. so far it is working
but i want when i click on the same place again that the previous image is displayed again.

this is not working, how do i fix this?

```
    <img id="lights-off" src="../images/ABC2.png" style="display: none;">
    <img id="lights-on" src="../images/ABC.png">


    const lightsOff = document.getElementById("lights-off");
    const lightsOn = document.getElementById("lights-on");
    let isChanged = false;
    
    lightsOn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        if (event.offsetX >= 0 && event.offsetX <= 100 && event.offsetY >= 0 && event.offsetY <= 20) {
            if(!isChanged){
                lightsOff.style.display = "block";
                lightsOn.style.display = "none";
                isChanged = true;
            } else {
                lightsOff.style.display = "none";
                lightsOn.style.display = "block";
                isChanged = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

I tryed to make some changes but it doenst work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a single delegated event listener to the page and inspect the `event` to only process images of interest. By toggling the display property based upon an images current display state you achieve the desired effect I think

```js
let col = document.querySelectorAll('img#lights-on,img#lights-off');

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLImageElement && e.offsetX >= 0 && e.offsetX <= 100 && e.offsetY >= 0 && e.offsetY <= 20) {
    col.forEach(img => {
      if (img && img.nodeType == 1) {
        img.style.display=( img.style.display == '' || img.style.display == 'block' ) ? 'none' : 'block';
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img id="lights-off" src="//www.collinsdictionary.com/images/thumb/apple_158989157_250.jpg" style="display: none;">
<img id="lights-on" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Banana-Single.jpg/680px-Banana-Single.jpg">
```

Comment: is it also possible to add pointer to that specifiek area ?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to effectively assign a custom cursor to a specific area of a page just govered by the `e.offsetX` & `e.offsetY` properties.

Comment: You might try with an [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) - I had limited success with thatbut it has promise

Answer (score 0):

you are listing only to  `lightsOn`
you should listen to both of the images:

```
const lightsOff = document.getElementById("lights-off");
const lightsOn = document.getElementById("lights-on");


function isInBorder(event){
    return event.offsetX >= 0 && event.offsetX <= 100 && event.offsetY >= 0 && event.offsetY <= 20
}

lightsOn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if (isInBorder(event)) {
        lightsOn.style.display = "none";
        lightsOff.style.display = "block";
    }
});

lightsOff.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if (isInBorder(event)) {
        lightsOff.style.display = "none";
        lightsOn.style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

Comment: i used this code but doenst work. why ?

Comment: @andre, oops had a mistake in the code, try not :), 
i've edited the mistake away

Comment: now it works, is it also possible to add pointer to that specifiek area by mouse over ? –

Comment: what do you mean? a cursor pointer ?
if so you can add to your CSS
```
#lights-off, #lights-on{
cursor:pointer ;
}
```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: yes a cursor pointer, but if I add this then the cursor pointer is working for the whole image, but I want that the pointer is going to show only on that specific part of the image.